# How to share data from iPhone app in Objective-C to Google Sheets

Tags: objective-c, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I am trying to share (send) user data from iPhone app in Objective-C to Google Sheets:

1. Require user login with Google account.
2. Share user data from iPhone application to Google Sheets.

I have searched on internet but not really solution found. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: What have you tried? What doesn't work?

Comment: Welcome to stack please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Then when you edit your question be sure to incldue a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I have learned from this link https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client-for-rest
But can't find the solution for my issue.